# UML automated generation for Netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I've installed UML plugin but I cant understand how create UML automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

[UML Diagrams for NetBeans 7.0](http://imagine.kicbak.com/blog/?p=58)

[Generating UML From the NetBeans IDE](https://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans)