# How to generate class diagrams and sequence diagrams from existing code?

Tags: java, netbeans, reverse-engineering, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I have a Java code which I need to generate the class diagrams and sequence diagrams. I am using netbeans, but the code is 100% pure hand coded. How can I generate the class diagrams and sequence diagrams for existing code using netbeans?

The code is separated into packages, so I need to generate class diagrams package wise. Which means, for an example, diagram 1 for package 1, diagram 2 for package 2 etc. Finally I need to take the generated GUI as an image.

Please help!

Comment: have you looked at previous questions on this topic? for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146111/creating-uml-class-diagrams-in-netbeans-7-1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, generating UML diagrams for code that you have written yourself is kind of pointless.  The value of UML is as a design aid and to a lesser extent as a reverse engineering aid.  If you are intent on generating code documentation for existing well-understood code, Javadoc is probably better value than UML, and a lot less work.

The other problem is that generated UML class diagrams tend to be ugly because they tend to include more detail than is necessary, and because you need a human eye to lay things out decently.  The same probably goes for sequence diagrams.

But if that hasn't convinced you, these links should help you do it.

- [UML Diagrams for NetBeans 7.0](http://imagine.kicbak.com/blog/?p=58)
- [Generating UML From the NetBeans IDE](https://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans)

<sub>(Disclaimer: scraped from this closed Question - [UML automated generation for Netbeans 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094415/uml-automated-generation-for-netbeans-7-1))</sub>

> Finally I need to take the generated GUI as an image.

Take a screen shot of the GUI using the tools provided by your OS.

Comment: yaya, documenting..My university work. I need a detailed design, there are some parts which are nt in original highlevel GUI, but in code. SO I need reverse engineering.

Comment: @Yohan - I think they probably intended you to do it the other way around.  Design using UML diagrams, then implement classes based on the diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

I just created UML diagrams for my uni project . Sad to see that Netbeans has stopped supporting UML plugin for its newer versions. In case you are also on a newer version like me (7.3 ) then you can make use of a third party tool namely yWorks UML Doclet to generate UML .

Its works really well . At least i am happy . See the way to use it [NetBeans 7.0 and 7.1 UML plugin](http://michelelepri.blogspot.sg/2012/03/netbeans-70-and-71-uml-plugin.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: does it generates sequence diagrams? Third party app also fine

Comment: yWorks seems to be pretty dangerous. Their license agreement says we need to keep their link in the output! That means, BUSTED!

Comment: @Yohan i dont really care if i should keep their link in their output . i can see that they use it to advertise their product . Its ok with me ! I comply to licenses !

Comment: @Yohan it doesnt seem to generate sequence diagrams. I am searching for one as well . Post here if you find something useful :-)